# How to scale all axes at once using the scale gizmo

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, gizmo

When modeling, it is sometimes good to be able to use the handles instead of using shortcuts.

In Maya, you can scale the object along the X, Y, or Z axis using handles or you can scale it along all axes using handles (that yellow handle in the middle).

Is there a way to likewise scale the object along all axes in Blender or is this something I need to suggest on Right-Click Select?

[image]

Comment: to scale in all axis just press "S" and move the mouse.

Comment: Yes, but what I was wondering was is there a way to scale it using handles. (The answer is down below)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It scales in all axis when you click in between the two white rings instead of on a handle